# Configure network Linux on VMware (Nat or Bridged)

Tags: linux, networking, vmware

Need to configure an static IP address, I'm doing tests with WordPress in a Virtual Machine with Linux (on VMWare Player) and I want a static IP on that VM and internet connection. I tried configurin the file /etc/network/interfaces like this:

> auto eth0
>   iface eth0 inet static
>   address 192.168.100.145
>   netmask 255.255.255.0

I need to set up a gateway too? And how I need to do this? My laptop is always changing from networks like home or school

What I need to configure VMware? NAT or Bridged? I discard Host-only because I need internet connection too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you change your network connection often, it makes little sens to use a static IP configuration. You see, when you change configuration in /etc/network/interfaces, you certainly need to specify the network and the gateway, besides mask and your own address (plus, if you wish, broadcast and dns-nameservers). The first three specs (gateway, network, mask) change from LAN to LAN, so it is possible that your chosen IP address belongs to a completely different network: in this case, you would be left incommunicado.

Also, it is possible that your chosen address is already taken, which would cause a number of difficult-to-diagnose malfunctions (just try it once, for pure fun, you'll see it).

As for syntax, a correct, simple configuration is:

```
 auto eth0
 iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.15.25 
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.15.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8
```

to which you may add pre-up/post-up/pre-down/post-down to specify actions to be executed before/after connection/disconnection.

If however you insist on retaining your xxx.xxx.xxx.145 address, you will have to learn how to listen to a network without having a proper IP address, to discover whether a 145 address has been given to someone already.